# Rails app unable to save anything after deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment

today I uploaded my app to server, and after seting it into development mode, and running of course rake tasks (rake db: migrate, and rade db: migrate RAILS_ENV="production") and well it just doesn't save anything.

The problem happens when I try to create any new items, it just goest to the listing of models...

Comment: Note: People may help you, but using "it's urgent to me" will actually **lower** your chances of getting an answer. It will get you, in the best case, a response saying "well, that's too bad" - the problem's urgency is not relevant to its content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it.

reason i asked was because i absolutely went through each and every one of my potential problems and took care of them, and well in the end none of them were the reason of such a failure. so then i went to the basics

and i basically had to clone my development environment on the production machine.

so i had to downgrade rails a couple of versions, and some gems too.

that took care of it, everything went on smoothly, so if anyone ever encounters such mysterous failures, give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague. I believe you're saying the app writes files to the server's hard drive. If that's what you're asking, I think the best guess is that something's wrong with file system permissions. Unfortunately, I can't say what is wrong without more details.